# Не могу понять, как оптимизировать код под многопроцессорность (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прошу простить за длинный кусок кода, но я никак не могу понять, что можно с этим кодом сделать для его оптимизации. Нужно серьёзно ускорить время выполнения программы (чем больше ускорение, тем лучше)
Сам пока ещё новичок, и это мой первый проект такого уровня. Прошу не кидатся минусами. Хотя бы не сразу.
Буду благодарен за любые способы оптимизации

```
links = []


# получить html код страницы

    def get_html(url):
        """ :return исходный HTML код страницы """
        r = requests.get(url)

        return r.text

# получить кол-во страниц

    def get_total_pages(html):
        """ :return кол-во страниц для дальнейшего парсинга """
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        pages = soup.find('div', class_='pages').find_all('a')[-1].get('href')
        total_pages = pages.split('=')[-1]

        return int(total_pages)


    def get_links(url):
        """ сбор ссылок для последующего парсинга товаров """
        global links

        html = get_html(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='item-inner')

        for div in divs:
            href = div.find('a')['href']

            links.append(href)

    # Парсинг самих полей товара
    def parse_product():
        """ парсинг товаров и занесение итогов в XLS файл """
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        full_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        # чтение и запись в файл
        path_file_xls = os.path.abspath("resources\parse.xls")
        path_file_out_xls = os.path.abspath("OUT\parse " + date + ".xls")

        start_id = gtc.get_start_id()
        product_id = gtc.get_start_id()
        line = 1  # строка, в котору будет идти запись

        book = xlrd.open_workbook(path_file_xls, on_demand=True, formatting_info=True)

        write_book = xlcopy(book)
        write_sheet = write_book.get_sheet(0)

        gtc.check_id_error()

        global links

        input_data = return_data()

        # данные берутся из другого файла
        for date_in in range(0, len(input_data)):
            url = input_data[date_in][0]
            base_url = input_data[date_in][1]
            category = input_data[date_in][2]
            image_directory = input_data[date_in][3]
            page_path = r'?&page='

            # А дальше ******...

            total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html(url))

            for i in range(1, total_pages + 1):
                url_gen = base_url + page_path + str(i)
                # get all links
                get_links(url_gen)

                print(url_gen)

            # ТУТ

            for link in links:

                print(link)

                html = get_html(link)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

                # name
                # # self.categories = categories
                # image
                # image_url
                # image_directory
                # price
                # description
                # stock

                # pages = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a')[-1].get('href')

                name = soup.find('h1', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'}).text
                image_url = soup.find('div', class_='general-img').find('img').get('src')
                image_name = soup.find('div', class_='general-img').find('img').get('src').split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
                print(image_name)

                # save product photo to "/photo/"
                response = requests.get(image_url)
                path_to_programm_folder = os.getcwd()
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    try:
                        h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
                        response, content = h.request(image_url)
                        out = open((path_to_programm_folder + '\photo' + image_directory + image_name), 'wb')
                        out.write(content)
                        out.close()
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        path_to_programm_folder = os.getcwd()
                        folder_name = path_to_programm_folder + '\photo' + image_directory
                        os.mkdir(folder_name)
                        print('Папка создана!')
                        h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
                        response, content = h.request(image_url)
                        out = open((path_to_programm_folder + '\photo' + image_directory + image_name), 'wb')
                        out.write(content)
                        out.close()
                # -------------------------------------------------------
                # h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
                # response, content = h.request(image_url)
                # out = open( (path_to_program_folder + '\photo' + image_directory + image_name), 'wb' )
                # out.write(content)
                # out.close()

                # вытянул строку и отсёк лишние 2 ноля через split
                # price = soup.find('div', class_='price').find('span', class_='num').text.strip().split(',')[0]
                price = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'price'}).text.split(',')[0].replace(' ', '')
                price = int(price)

                try:
                    description = soup.find('div', class_='htmlDataBlock').text.strip()
                except:
                    description = name
                if '&nbsp;' in description:
                    description = description.replace('&nbsp;', '')

                # TODO доработать. Тут срань, а не код
                # проверка ниличия товара
                stock = False
                availability_check = str(soup.find('div', class_='available-true'))
                if 'display:none' in availability_check:
                    stock = False
                else:
                    stock = True
                    # layout в таблицу
                    write_sheet.write(line, 34, '0:')

                # # TODO for test
                # print(name)
                # print(image_url)
                # print(image_name)
                # print(price)
                # print(description)

                # print('\n')
                # print('id = ' + str(product_id))
                # print(link)
                # print(name)
                # print(image_url)
                # print(image_name)
                # print(price)
                # print(description)
                # print(stock)

                # id в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 0, product_id)
                # name в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 1, name)
                write_sheet.write(line, 11, name)
                write_sheet.write(line, 29, name)
                write_sheet.write(line, 30, name)
                # category в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 2, ("'" + category))
                # quantity в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 10, 1)
                # TODO поправть. ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
                # image_name в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 13, ('/catalog' + image_directory + image_name))
                # shipping в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 14, "yes")
                # price в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 15, price)
                # points в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 16, 0)
                # date (загрузки и модификации) в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 17, full_date)
                write_sheet.write(line, 18, full_date)
                # date_available в таблицу. По умолчанию актуальность товара стоит 30 дней
                # TODO посмотреть, что за дичь
                write_sheet.write(line, 18, full_date)
                # full_out_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
                # full_out_date_str = full_out_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                # write_sheet.write(line, 19, full_out_date_str)
                # weight в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 20, 0)
                # weight_unit в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 21, "кг")
                # length в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 22, 0)

                print(product_id)

                # width в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 23, 0)
                # height в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 24, 0)
                # length_unit в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 25, "см")
                # status в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 26, "true")
                # tax_class_id в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 27, 0)
                # description(ru-ru) в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 28, description)
                # stock_status_id в таблицу
                if (stock):
                    write_sheet.write(line, 32, 7)
                else:
                    write_sheet.write(line, 32, 5)
                # store_ids в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 33, 0)

                # sort_order в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 37, 1)
                # subtract в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 38, "true")
                # minimum в таблицу
                write_sheet.write(line, 39, 1)

                print(datetime.datetime.now())

                product_id += 1
                line += 1

            write_book.save(path_file_out_xls)
            print("ГОТОВО")

            # Очистка links[]
            links.clear()

        #  функция для записи в последнюю страницу (ProductSEOKeywords)
        # ААААААААААРРРРРРРРРР!!!!!!!!!
        try:
            path_file_not_ready = os.path.abspath("OUT\parse " + date + ".xls")
            path_to_save_ready_file = os.path.abspath("OUT\parseREADY " + date + ".xls")

            book = xlrd.open_workbook(path_file_not_ready, on_demand=True, formatting_info=True)
            print("Файл открыт успешно")

            write_book_for_last_page = xlcopy(book)
            write_sheet_for_last_page = write_book_for_last_page.get_sheet(9)
            print("Write sheet open")

            # сама запись product_id в ProductSEOKeywords
            num_of_line = 1

            for i in range(start_id, (product_id)):
                write_sheet_for_last_page.write(num_of_line, 0, i)
                # store_id  таблицу
                write_sheet_for_last_page.write(num_of_line, 1, 0)
                num_of_line += 1
                print(i)

            write_book_for_last_page.save(path_to_save_ready_file)

            # save id for next parse
            gtc.save_id(str(product_id + 1))

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Неа, ты программа туда не ходи, ты выше в блок try ходи!")
            sys.exit(-404)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_product()
```

Answer (score 1):

Оберните тот код, который Вы хотите оптимизировать, в отдельную функцию.
Мне кажется, что Вам лучше будет сделать это с циклом `for link in links`.
У меня в примере созданная функция называется `very_long_func`.

После чего, с помощью модуля `multiprocessing` создавайте в цикле процессы, передавая нужные аргументы для целевой функции. В Вашем случае будет удобно передавать `link`.

***Пример:***

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def very_long_func(x):
    sleep(5)
    print(x)


def main():
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=very_long_func, args=(i, ))
        p.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Обратите внимание, что Вы увидите повышение производительности только в том случае, если на Вашей машине более 1 ядра\процессора. В ином случае она упадёт, причём раза в 2.*

**UPD:**

Использование глобальных переменных - ужасное архитектурное решение, но оно не мешает оптимизировать код.
Просто функции, которые будут выполняться в нескольких процессах не должны обращаться к глобальной области видимости.

В Вашем случае код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


links = []


def change_global_link_list():
    global links
    links = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def parse_link(link):
    sleep(5)
    print(f'Парсинг {link} завершён')


def main():
    change_global_link_list()
    for link in links:
        p = Process(target=parse_link, args=(link, ))
        p.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: проблема в том, что тогда надо отказаться от использования глобального массива "links".
А у меня в голове нет пока идей, как это сделать. 
Повторюсь, в программировании новичок, так что сюда закинул код только как понял, что сам не могу понять.

Спасибо)

Comment: @КрисРэкфилд Использовать глобальные переменные - идея ужасная :) Лучше, чтобы функция возвращала этот массив. Но это не проблема для оптимизации. Главное -  чтобы функция, которая будет выполняться несколькими процессами, не трогала глобальные переменные. А этого вполне можно достичь и в Вашем коде. Я обновил ответ, приблизив его к модели Вашего кода.

Comment: Тогда остается только один вопрос. Я честно говоря уже думал сделать именно так. Только ступор у меня вызвал один момент. А точнее то, что мне надо что-то сделать для записи в таблицу.

Можно ли как то передать экземпляр writesheet в другую функцию чтобы запись шла в ней?

Comment: @КрисРэкфилд Попробуйте. Точно сказать не могу, но, скорее всего, `writesheet` можно передавать как аргумент функции. Но это должна быть обычная функция.